# AngularJS with Django getting: xhr.send(post || null);

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I have been googling this for an hour, so I hope someone can help.

I have an AngularJS Controller:

```
conciergeControllers.controller('GuestCtrl', function GuestCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Message, Guest) {
  $scope.messages = {};

  Guest.get({id:$routeParams.guestId}, function(response) {
    $scope.guest = response;
    $scope.to = response.phone_number;
    $scope.messages = response.messages;
  });

  $scope.submitMessage = function(body) {
    var message = new Message({body: body});
    message.$save(function() {
      $scope.messages.unshift(message);
    })
  }

});
```

But, everytime I post in my Form, it gives me this error:

```
xhr.send(post || null);
```

I have a simple form.  Here it is:

```
<div class="message-container">
  <input value="[[ guest.name ]]" type="text" class="new-message-input" id="new-message" ng-model="body">
  <button class="btn-message" id="message" ng-click="submitMessage(body)">Send</button>
</div>
```

It seems like I need to convert the `Form` data to `xhr`, or maybe add a crsf cookie, but am not sure what may be causing this?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Causing *what*? You haven't shown any errors. Your "error" is a perfectly normal function call.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, sorry for my question being incomplete.  I was trying to use this with `django-rest-framework` and the error was actually an authentication error, but I was just seeing a 500 error, so was confused.  Thanks.